# Trying to make a Flexbox inside a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

So here is the trouble Im having. Im kind of trying to make a flexbox inside of a flexbox. Im not sure how to explain it so I drew it out to try to make it easier. It will start it an outer div that I call the grandparent div. Inside this dive will be three divs that I call the parent divs. inside each of those divs will be 2 divs that I call the child divs.

When it is viewed in computer mode the 3 parent divs will be side by side with the child divs on top of each other inside.

When it is in tablet mode it will the parent divs will be on top of each other with the child divs side by side.
When it is in cell phone mode it will have the parent divs on top of each other with the child divs on top of each other as well.

I drew a picture to give a better idea. If anyone can help you have no clue how thankful I will be
[Sketch of what Im trying to go for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIC1C.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question and problem

Comment: It seems you're not sure where to start.  I whipped up [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-kare-tnbfi) and starting messing around.  I recommend you learn abour media queries in css, as well as the flex wrap property.  I would flesh it out a little more but I have to go, hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: That is really close to what I had but is really helpful.  I forgot to give each of the media queries a different name which I think made it confusing for the browser to figure out which one to react to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grandparent {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 10px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent {
  border: 10px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  flex: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .grandparent {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
  }    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**LIVE**

https://codepen.io/wilsonbalderrama/pen/yLyRZpM

Comment: SUCCESS!!! That is exactly what I was trying to go for.  Thank you so much, If I knew you in person I would buy you a drink.

Comment: glad to help, don't forget to check the answer.